# Elasticsearch distinct count of parents

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have created a query for ES, and I am attempting to include aggregations. These will be displayed on the side of the page the user sees, so they can filter their results down further. Each of these will have a count next to them as well. Let me explain the model I'm working with so you can understand the count that I am searching for.

Here is an example of my index:

```
"mappings": {
  "teacher": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "studentCount": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  },
  "student": {
    "_parent": {
      "type": "teacher"
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "classesCount": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say someone does a wildcard search. They would receive back  a list of all the teachers. On the side, they would receive the top 50 occurring students names with which the user can further filter their results. This list of filters needs a count of the number of teachers that have that particular student. However, there is the possibility that one teacher can have a single student more than once (e.g. the teacher moved from teaching 1st grade to 2nd grade and had many of the same students both years).

Here is an example of my query to ES (I use Nest):

```
return await elasticClient.SearchAsync<TeacherModel>(s => s
  .Index(index)
  .Type("teacher")
  .Query(q => builtQuery)
  .Aggregations(a => a
    .Children<StudentModel>("Students", c => c
      .Type("student")
      .Aggregations(ca => ca
        .Terms("Students", t => t
          .Field("name")
          .Size(50))))));
```

However, since the DocCount is counting the number of child documents, it is usually higher than the actual number of teacher records that correspond to that particular student. I have also tried adding a cardinality aggregation to this

```
....
  .Terms("Students", t => t
          .Field("name")
          .Size(50)
          .Aggregations(aa => aa
            .Cardinality("Count", co => co
              .Field("_parent"))))))));
```

This is able to get me closer, and sometimes it is even right on. I have tried tuning this with the PrecisionThreshold value, but even then it is sometimes off by thousands of records when dealing with ~2,000,000 teacher documents. Is there a way to get an exact or more accurate count of these parent documents?

Comment: I am assuming you are using multiple shards for your index. If thats the case your aggregations might not be accurate. This link might help: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-approximate-counts

Comment: @jay: Yes, we have 5 shards for our index. I appreciate the link, but we have already done quite a bit of research over the last few days reading over elasticsearch documentation and questions pertaining to our predicament. The other aggregations have counts that are always correct since they are fields directly on the parent type. However, getting the count that we need is proving to be very difficult. We want to be as accurate as possible, and, although only a few percent off, thousands of records difference between our cardinality count and the actual count is too much.

Comment: The performance of our queries is diminishing with each attempt. The children aggregation slows us down by a few seconds, and the cardinality aggregation on that slows us down even more. I know it is asking a lot, but we need to be as quick and accurate as possible.

Comment: Can you post the actual search template (json)? Also an example of a query & response and which number is not being calculated properly?

Comment: @jay: It's not that they're being calculated improperly, it's just the DocCount is not the actual count I need, and the cardinality aggregation I'm currently having to use is not accurate enough and too performance costly. I am not sure if I can get the JSON going out. I will see if I can get that, and I will get a response posted as well.